# Doctrine ORM not creating foreign keys in database generated from YaML specification

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine, yaml

I am using doctrine with Symfony. I have specified my database entities using YaML. I am able to generate the database from my YaML file - however, to my horror, when I inspect the generated tables - *some* entities are losing the foreign key references etc.

Doctrine seems to be failing silently, as no errors are emitted on the screen, and the `doctrine:schema:update --force` task runs and reports that it was completed successfully.

Here is an example of one such entity:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    repositoryClass: UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }

    manyToOne:
        user_type:
            targetEntity: UserType
            joinColumn:
                name: user_type_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: false
                onDelete: RESTRICT
                onUpdate: CASCADE

    manyToOne:
        user_title:
            targetEntity: UserTitle
            joinColumn:
                name: user_type_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: false
                onDelete: RESTRICT
                onUpdate: CASCADE

    oneToMany:
        actions:
            targetEntity: UserAction
            mappedBy: User

    oneToMany:
        type_roles:
            targetEntity: UserTypeRole
            mappedBy: User

    uniqueConstraints:
        idxu_user_lname_eml:
            columns: [last_name, user_email]

    indexes:
        idx_user_name:
            columns: [last_name, first_name]
        idx_user_email:
            columns: user_email            


    fields:
        first_name:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false
            unique: false

        middle_name:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: true
            unique: false 

        last_name:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false
            unique: false     

        email:
            type: string
            length: 32
            column: user_email
            unique: true
            options:
                fixed: true
                comment: User's email address

        address_line1:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: false

        address_line2:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        address_line3:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        town_city:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        county_district:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        state_region:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        post_zipcode:
            type: string
            length: 12
            nullable: true

        country:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        login_count:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: true
                default: 0

        last_login:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
```

Here is the table generated from this specification above:

```
mysql> describe user;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_type_id    | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| first_name      | varchar(32)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| middle_name     | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name       | varchar(64)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| user_email      | char(32)         | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| address_line1   | varchar(128)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address_line2   | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address_line3   | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| town_city       | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| county_district | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state_region    | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| post_zipcode    | varchar(12)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country         | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| login_count     | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| last_login      | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
16 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong, that is preventing the foreign relationships from being created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the benefit of hindsight (and probably, a good night's sleep), the solution to the problem, is obvious: I had specified the entity incorrectly,in my YaML, this is what the correct YaML representation should be:

```
AppBundle\Entity\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    repositoryClass: UserRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }

    manyToOne:
        user_type:
            targetEntity: UserType
            joinColumn:
                name: user_type_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: false
                onDelete: RESTRICT
                onUpdate: CASCADE

        user_title:
            targetEntity: UserTitle
            joinColumn:
                name: user_title_id
                referencedColumnName: id
                nullable: false
                onDelete: RESTRICT
                onUpdate: CASCADE

    oneToMany:
        actions:
            targetEntity: UserAction
            mappedBy: User

        roles:
            targetEntity: UserTypeRole
            mappedBy: User

    uniqueConstraints:
        idxu_user_lname_eml:
            columns: [user_email]

    indexes:
        idx_user_name:
            columns: [last_name, first_name]           


    fields:
        first_name:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: false
            unique: false

        middle_name:
            type: string
            length: 32
            nullable: true
            unique: false 

        last_name:
            type: string
            length: 64
            nullable: false
            unique: false     

        email:
            type: string
            length: 32
            column: user_email
            unique: true
            options:
                fixed: true
                comment: User's email address

        address_line1:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: false

        address_line2:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        address_line3:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        town_city:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        county_district:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        state_region:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        post_zipcode:
            type: string
            length: 12
            nullable: true

        country:
            type: string
            length: 128
            nullable: true

        login_count:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: true
                default: 0

        last_login:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

This section :

```
manyToOne:
    user_type:
        targetEntity: UserType
        joinColumn:
            name: user_type_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: false
            onDelete: RESTRICT
            onUpdate: CASCADE

manyToOne:
    user_title:
        targetEntity: UserTitle
        joinColumn:
            name: user_type_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: false
            onDelete: RESTRICT
            onUpdate: CASCADE

oneToMany:
    actions:
        targetEntity: UserAction
        mappedBy: User

oneToMany:
    type_roles:
        targetEntity: UserTypeRole
        mappedBy: User
```

should look like that :

```
manyToOne:
    user_type:
        targetEntity: UserType
        joinColumn:
            name: user_type_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: false
            onDelete: RESTRICT
            onUpdate: CASCADE
    user_title:
        targetEntity: UserTitle
        joinColumn:
            name: user_type_id
            referencedColumnName: id
            nullable: false
            onDelete: RESTRICT
            onUpdate: CASCADE

oneToMany:
    actions:
        targetEntity: UserAction
        mappedBy: User
    type_roles:
        targetEntity: UserTypeRole
        mappedBy: User
```

In YaML, when multiple keys are defined with the same name, it just overrides the previous value of that key.

Comment: Your answer fails to include the recommended change (i.e. use different names for different keys). In any event, even with the modification suggested, the FKs are not generated correctly

Comment: Check that in your PHP entity that your relationships are correctly implemented. Doctrine checks the associations only in the owning side (entities where the association is defined with `inversedBy`). If you create an association from the inversed side of the relation, you have to make sure that the association is also created in the owning side of the association. For example, in the `User` class : `public function addAction(UserAction $userAction) { $this->actions[] = $userAction; $userAction->setUser($this); }`